# is Sigmoid activation function better than Leaky Relu?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I recently implemented a neural network from scratch in python with one hidden layer on the iris dataset for classification. Initially i applied Leaky relu for hidden layer acrivations and got an accuracy around 40% then i switched to sigmoid and found that accuracy improved drastically to 93% accuracy.

How is that possible?

I learned from Andrew ng  lectures that Leaky relu is a best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My hypothesis is that you found a configuration (learning rate, batch size, number of hidden nodes, etc.) which happened to be better for the sigmoid network than the Leaky ReLU network. I assume that there's an alternative configuration for which the Leaky ReLU network is better than the sigmoid network.

As an aside, the main motivation of ReLU-type activations is that they work better in deep networks, where sigmoid and tanh networks tend to get saturated and the gradient vanishes. Using a network with 1 hidden layer is not necessarily going to highlight the contrast between sigmoid and ReLU activations.

I would caution against drawing any general conclusions from a single experiment using the Iris data. It's a small data set where one of the classes is linearly separable from the rest, so it's only useful as a toy problem; it's just not very complex.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "best" activation function. If there were, all the neural network architectures would stick to the single "best" one, while what we see is something opposite: different neural networks, or even different layers of single network, use [different activation functions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115258/comprehensive-list-of-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-with-pros-cons). Some of them, like [ReLU](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226923/why-do-we-use-relu-in-neural-networks-and-how-do-we-use-it), are more popular then others, but [there are cases where they don't work](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188040/my-relu-network-fails-to-launch/) and you need to use different activation functions instead. People usually do what you did: start with what is currently known to be most promising solution, but if it fails, try also the alternatives.